# create a sequence in postgresql and apply it to a table

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a sequence that starts with 1000 and increments by one unit. Then, apply this sequence to the variable "identification" of my table "person". The number of records in the table "person" is 958, so it should increment to the end by default. In addition, I want the numbering to be based on the Age field sorted in descending order

I have tried to do something similar to the following but I get no results. I have also tried to put an order by age desc in the middle of the sentence also without result. Any idea?

```
TABLE PERSON (Name, Surname, City, Identification, Age)

CREATE SEQUENCE seq 
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1000;

ALTER TABLE person
ALTER COLUMN identification DEFAULT nextval('seq');
```

Thnak you!

Comment: You need to `UPDATE` the already existing rows. A `DEFAULT` won't work "backwards in time".

Comment: Yes I know that there are easier ways to do it, but the particularity is that I am forced to use sequences for this example.